non-symmetrical elements in two groups that should be symmetrical
I am using Gmsh to generate a mesh that includes two groups, the upper and the lower group. I expected mesh in the two groups is symmetrical. But in fact, the upper one has 59 elements, while the lower group has 57 elements. Could anyone kindly help check what is wrong here?

below is the .geo file:
//+
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(2) = {0.05, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(3) = {0.05, 0.05, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(4) = {0.05, 0.1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(5) = {0, 0.1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(6) = {0, 0.058, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(7) = {0, 0.042, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(8) = {0, 0.05, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(9) = {0.008, 0.05, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(10) = {0.005656854, 0.055656854249492, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(11) = {0.005656854, 0.044343145750508, 0, 1.0};
//+
Line(1) = {1, 2};
//+
Line(2) = {3, 2};
//+
Line(3) = {3, 4};
//+
Line(5) = {4, 5};
//+
Line(6) = {6, 5};
//+
Circle(7) = {6, 8, 10};
//+
Circle(8) = {10, 8, 9};
//+
Circle(9) = {9, 8, 11};
//+
Circle(10) = {11, 8, 7};
//+
Line(11) = {7, 1};
//+
Line(12) = {9, 3};
//+
Curve Loop(1) = {11, 1, -2, -12, 9, 10};
//+
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
//+
Curve Loop(2) = {12, 3, 5, -6, 7, 8};
//+
Plane Surface(2) = {2};
//+
Physical Curve("LICHA", 13) = {7, 8, 9, 10};
//+
Physical Curve("DOX1_FIX", 14) = {-6, 11};
//+
Physical Surface("Group 1", 15) = {1};
//+
Physical Surface("Group 2", 16) = {2};
//+
Transfinite Curve {3} = 4 Using Progression 1.05;
//+
Transfinite Curve {2} = 4 Using Progression 1.05;
//+
Transfinite Curve {6} = 4 Using Progression 1.05;
//+
Transfinite Curve {11} = 4 Using Progression 1.05;
//+
Transfinite Curve {5, 1} = 3 Using Beta 1;
//+
Transfinite Curve {12} = 10 Using Beta 1;
//+
Transfinite Curve {7, 8, 9, 10} = 2 Using Beta 1;

I expected symmetrical mesh in upper and lower groups. Ii checked the parameters to be the same but it didn't change the results.

If you define the second Curve Loop similar to the first one, you will have desired result. Namely, change the Curve Loop(2) = {12, 3, 5, -6, 7, 8}; to the Curve Loop(2) = {-6,5,3,12,8,7};.
